# Achieve twitch effect with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation

Is it at all possible to create a static/tv interference/twitch effect *similar* to what was used for the Battlefield 3 intro in jQuery? What I'm wanting to do is "fade out" a div, but have it do something more interesting like the twitch effect. I don't know if this is remotely possible with just jQuery or not.

You can see the BF3 intro effect [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H4_DelSWF8&feature=related).

Comment: http://Processing.js could I know. I would think it would require `canvas`, although maybe `svg` could fashion it?

Comment: If you have the math chops or understand fractal design, you might see if you can adapt some of Jared Tarbell's [open source designs](http://levitated.net/gravityIndex.html). He used at this point I believe a Flash port of Processing in Java.

Comment: processing wouldn't work in ie8 or lower though would it?

Comment: It wouldn't work in 9. You're stuck in SVG land if you're worried about browser support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a framework that makes it easier for you to develop JavaScript, it doesn't come with much advanced UI stuff. [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/), on the other hand, has a few features, but I nothing as fancy as what you want. The closest you'll get here is [jQuery UI's shake](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Shake). If you speed that up, it might begin to look twitchy.

As pointed out in the comment by [Jarred Farrish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451969/jared-farrish), [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) might be what you're looking for:

> Processing.js makes your data visualizations, digital art, interactive animations, educational graphs, video games, etc. work using web standards and without any plug-ins.

Comment: Hmm... I at least get a nod, don't I? `;)`

Comment: @JaredFarrish I'm sorry, hope that's better. :)

Comment: If you haven't seen his work, checkout [Jared Tarbell](http://levitated.net/gravityIndex.html). Some of them are Java, but the rest are Flash and he's a master Processing artist. Truly unbelievable.

Comment: i think that should work. maybe combined with a lower opacity it should be enough

Answer (score 6):

A 'possible' way to do this could be to simply change the background image of the div rapidly using jquery.

I whipped up a quick demo to show you what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ssGdz/

You could theoretically replicate that BF3 intro if you rotated between several images.

**P.S** I had a hunch this could potentially explode older browsers, but I opened it up in IE6 and  it ran smoothly.